# Does "no nothing" make any sense?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I could never make sense out of the largely informal and colloquial phrase, `no nothing`. Minus minus equals plus. So literally, `no nothing` comes to mean `something` or `anything`. But it is almost always used in the opposite sense.

> Exams over. No worries, no studies, **no nothing**!

Why and how was it coined?

Simply `nothing` serves the job well. Why was it even thought of?

Comment: Reduplication lends emphasis. Language isn't algebra. Things don't "cancel out".

Comment: Note that your question is not valid unless it provides some context/examples of the usage you ask about.

Comment: Can you give a full sentence in which this occurs? Otherwise we can't tell.

Comment: @DanBron In many cases, language does work like mathematics. As an instance, "You are not unkind." here `not` reverses the negativity of `unkind`

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine The thing with math is you can *count on it* to act like math -- in fact, that is the distinguishing feature of math. You cannot so count on language. Because negatives negate other negatives in one context is no indication at all that they will do so in another context, no matter how seemingly similar. In fact, in certain languages, to negate something you *must* use a double negative. The best possible advice is not to try to model language like mathematics, no expect it to act like mathematics, no ball or try to argue with it when it doesn't. It simply does not work that way

Comment: It usually concludes a list of pessimistic affirmations. “*[I have] no job, no house, no car, no nothing*.” In other words, the speaker is emphasizing their misfortune. P.S I wouldn't place your "real" age on your profile page, if I were you. It seems you've reached the legal minimum age but that means you were underage when you registered 21 months ago. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/how-do-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old

Comment: "Minus minus equals plus"- unless it doesn't. This is a matter of negative concord (here promoted by a desire for parallel structure) vs double negation. Some folk would say "I couldn't never make sense out of ..." In Standard English, *anything* is mandated as the negative polarity item ( no(t) anything), but some dialects are less strict on this matter, and *no nothing* is an idiomatic example of it in standard English. It wasn't coined, it has existed forever. And it somehow infiltrated Standard English's poorly patrolled encampment. See Wiki- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative

Comment: Negative *times* negative yields positive, that's true; but negative *plus* negative yields negative. An analogy to mathematics means one has to choose the correct analogy: which is another reason not to make simplistic mathematical analogies to language.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Can you check this (my recent question) out: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394295/a-word-that-refers-to-a-shrill-sound-vibrating-in-someones-ears-and-alerting-th? It's a single word request based on a given context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression used to emphasize that you mean nothing at all.

***[No nothing](https://www.google.it/search?q=no%20nothing%20meaning&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=no%20nothing%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3450j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#spf=1):***

(informal)

> (concluding a list of negatives) nothing at all.
>
> - ‘how could you solve it with no clues, no witnesses, no nothing?’

(ODO)

Answer (score -4):

However, technically the phrase "I don't have no nothing" would be correct, saying "I have nothing". To say "I don't have nothing" or "I have no nothing" should mean "I have something".

But nowadays this is thrown out of the window.

Comment: Was this ***ever*** the case? Has there ever been any period in the entire history of English when the phrase "no nothing" would have meant *anything*. The earliest I can find this phrase in Google books is in 1817, when Lord Byron wrote in a letter *"no prose, no verse, no nothing?"* Pretty similar to the OP's quote, actually.